# Nil id causing routing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models: posts, comments and questions. Comments belong to posts and questions belong to comments. I'm trying to link from my posts show page to my questions show page. The posts show page is calling a partial _comments which the link is in. The problem is that the link goes to the questions index instead of the questions show because the question.id is nil. The URL looks like this:

```
/comments/19/questions/
```

The routes:

```
comment_question GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions/:id(.:format)          questions#show
comment_questions GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions(.:format)            questions#index
```

The link in the _comments partial:

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
<% comment.questions.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(3).each do |question| %>  
<%= link_to question.title, comment_question_path(comment, question) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The partial is called in the posts show page with this:

```
<%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
```

I changed the link to this:

```
<%= url_for :controller => 'questions', :action => 'show', :comment_id => comment.id, :id => question.id %>
```

but got this error:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :id=>nil, :comment_id=>20}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you add the url your browser is showing at the time of this error?

Comment: localhost:3000/posts/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't nil, the question object just has no ID attached to it.

```
<% comment.questions.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(3).each do |question| %>
```

That line will build a query similar to the following (ignoring joins with comments):

```
SELECT title FROM questions
```

When you pass that to `comment_question_path(comment, question)` it just reads the attribute, it doesn't try to fetch it from the database. The ID in that question object will be `nil` because you haven't queried for it, hence why it's building a link with a nil question ID.

If you really want to use `select`, use `comment.questions.select([:id, :title])` instead.

If you don't care about using select, just use `comment.questions` instead.

More info on `select`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: btw i don't need to use select, any alternative that gives me the last two comments titles works.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the select syntax and gave an alternative to select too.